# Database schema for calendar application

Tags: database, database-design, architecture, calendar

I'm creating a calendar application in which each date has one of 3 states: available, maybe available, and unavailable. Trying to figure out the best schema for this situation.

One thought might be to have a UserDate model with a field `state`. The problem with this is that the DB will have `#-of-users- x 365` rows for each year - seems like it would grow too quickly for a modestly sized app.

Another thought might be to have a default state, and only create a UserDate object when the user has signified that their availability on that date is different from the default. This seems convoluted though.

Has anyone dealt with this situation before? Any suggestions on the best way to go about this?

Comment: Why not just default to something [maybe], then make date entries for anything that is different/user specified.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new user, you do not want to be inserting records for the next 50 years of their life.  Only creating the UserDate object when there is a non-default value is what you should do.

You could consider storing a range of dates for a user if you are likely to have lots of consecutive dates with the same status.  For example, if they are unavailable for all of December, then this could be represented as a single row.

Think about the sort of information you want to extract from your database, and how difficult this will be with each of your possible designs.